# QGraphicsView with automatic items placing

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qgraphicsview

I would like to write an asset browser using QGraphicsView. It's a little different from examples using QGraphicsView and QGraphicsItems, because I want only one scrollbar and I want items to move automatically, when the viewport size changes. For example, when viewport width is large enough to display 4 asssets, they should be displayed like this:

```
aaaa
aaaa
aa
```

but when viewport is shrinked and can only contain 3 in a row, it should display them like this:

```
aaa
aaa
aaa
a
```

I wouldn't like to have to move those asset's by myself and let the graphics view manage them all. Is it somehow possible?

I have written once such a thing, but using QWidget and paintEvent, drawing all assets myself and keeping track of how many assets can be displayed in a row. Can it be done simpler with QGraphicsView?

Comment: "QGraphicsView with automatic" is a title that doesn't say much about the question. Consider changing it...

Comment: Thanks, I must have forgotten about finishing the title.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

QGraphicsView supports layouts. What you have to do is implement your own layout manager, inheriting from QGraphicsLayout.

For the layout you require, take a look at the Flow Layout example of Qt. Converting that example will give you a QGraphicsFlowLayout. Add your QGraphicsItems to this layout and set your QGraphicsView's layout to that layout, and that would do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me you want a list, not a graphics view.  A list can be set to display things wrapping around like you desire.  See the [puzzle example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-puzzle-example.html), paying attention to the list of puzzle pieces on the left.  It looks pretty simple to set up for the case presented.

Of course, if you really want it in a graphics view, I suppose you could add a list to the view and use it there.

Answer (score -2):

I would use a custom layout to do this. Try to create your custom Layout class that inherits from QGraphicsLayout and manage the way it is placing items.